# Log in and delay second activity until results are posted

Tags: android, post, authentication, delay

All! I am pretty new to Developing Android. I have run into many issues already and solved most of them myself, and some by searching here and on other sites. The problem I currently face now, I can't seem to find a solution for. It is close to what others on here have asked, but I can't find anything for my problem.

I am working on the beginning stages of my first big app, in which a user signs in to the fist page and is then allowed access to the rest of the app and features with. I am using basic examples right now of a simple log in app and it works fine, but when I try to delay the first activity from calling the second one until the results are posted, either it posts and doesn't call the second activity, or it doesn't post the results and moves on anyways. I am also currently trying to bundle the results and display them in the second activity. I Will change that later though, I just need to see if it will work right.

Here is my code:(not sure if I'm doing this right. It's my first time!)

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Login button clicked
    ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    ok.setOnClickListener(this);

    result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbl_result);


    final Handler handler1 = new Handler();
    handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    final Bundle b = new Bundle();

                    EditText txt1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    EditText txt2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.lbl_result);

                    b.putString("ID", txt1.getText().toString());
                    b.putString("PW", txt2.getText().toString());

                    final Handler handler2 = new Handler();
                    handler2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            final Intent myIntent = new Intent(TempActivity.this, TempActivity2.class);             
                            myIntent.putExtras(b);
                            startActivity(myIntent);
                        }
                    }, 3000);                
                }
            });
        }
    }, 4000);
}
```

Am I just going about this the wrong way? Any help is greatly appreciated! I hate being a noob! Let me know if anymore information is needed!

Answer (score 0):

Ohhhh... i dont know.. if it is actually right.. but as far as i understand your code... you are using

```
 handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
```

and in its runnable

```
  public void run() {


ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

here.. you are setting onClickListener.. and it will happen after 4 seconds.. because of this line..

```
  }, 4000);
```

so if you click before 4 seconds.. i think onclicklistener is not being set... so give some time.. like 4 seconds after the application starts
.. and then try clicking... i think then it should work..

Comment: Thanks for responding! It still doesn't post before moving on. I should also mention that It FC's sometimes unless I disable this: 

EditText txt2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.lbl_result);

and:

b.putString("PW", txt2.getText().toString());

It's so confusing to me!